How can I convert ±10 V input to 0-10 V w/ run/stop/reverse signals?
I have a CNC lathe and the DC spindle motor went out. It's too expensive to replace, so I'm going with an AC motor and VFD.
The original control outputs -10 V as full speed reverse, 0 V stop, and 10 V is full speed forward.
My new VFD has 0-10 V for speed and has specific start, stop, and reverse signals. I have some Raspberry Picos laying around, but I'm not 100% sure on how to go about the circuit. Using the Picos would be nice, but I'm not opposed to getting another microcontroller if there's another better suited to the task.

I feel like a lathe would very likely have a warranty on it considering that it's a rather large piece of machinery. Couldn't you replace it that way instead of risk voiding that warranty?

A friend of mine rebuilt his Bridgeport CNC AC servos into BLDC servos which were powerful , efficient and low cost.

@Colin if it's still in warranty of course

@ChrisH Sorry, yes, that's what I was implying. I would imagine that these big machines have a rather lengthy warranty, minimum of 5 years if the vendor is stingy.

Here is essentially @Carl's idea using a small number of inexpensive components. Up to you to convert the +/-11V signals into something your controller will accept. Below about +/-120mV (1.2% of full speed) the STOP signal is asserted. Adjust the 100Ω resistor if that is too low or too high. It is assumed that the STOP signal overrides the others.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

You could use discrete circuits also.
Example is an op amp IC in a precision full-wave rectifier circuit to convert the 0 to ±10V signal to a 0 to +10V signal, and a analog comparator IC to detect the polarity for forward and reverse.
Another comparator could detect when the voltage is near zero, and generate a Stop signal if needed.
Addendum: Below is my take on the circuit with LTspice simulation.  It requires only one 12V supply.


Would the rectifier work with negative DC voltage or is that what the op amps would fix?

Yes, the op amp would convert the negative voltage to a positive, while passing the positive voltage with no change.

What is the required duration for the Start and Stop signals, and at what point in the 0 to 10V signal should they appear.

Or are the Start and Stop signals coming from separate switches?

I suggest another BAT54 on U1's input. In case it powers up with Vin negative.
